# Java Applications Crash when Browse Control Used

Tags: java, windows

Windows 10 Pro machine - Every app I have that depends on JRE that I try to install or run closes unexpectedly when a browse control is used. It appears to be an older browse control version because anything that looks like file explorer opens with no issues. I tried to install STM32CubeMX and when the dialog box that asks where to install the program appears, there is a control that looks like a folder. I click on that and the install app closes. If I manually type in the path and install, when I run the program and click a link that says load a project, the program closes. This happens with every JRE dependent app I try to install or run.

I tried numerous things to fix this. I uninstalled JRE and reinstalled the latest version. I tried uninstalling JRE and installing older versions. I tried using JavaRa to clean whatever I could between installs. I did a disk cleanup deleting all temporary files. I used the Java Console and cleared the cache and temporary files. I searched for log files so I could at least get a clue of what is happening but have turned up empty. I searched for a day looking for Java related issues to mine and it seems I am the only one on the planet with a legacy browse control issue (in a Java / JRE dependent app).

I have an odd issue and not sure where to look to fix other than reinstalling windows, even though it appears to be a JRE issue. Should I be looking towards windows and not Java as the culprit? What log files and where should I look at, or enable?

Another issue is occurring that started the same time this issue started. I go to install one of these apps... STM32 System Workbench, STLINK Utility, STM32CUBE... and I get a Java dialog telling me that an instance of that install is already running. I do not see any instance of the process in task manager, and it happens fresh out of a reboot.

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I did a windows file integrity scan and no anomalies were found. I am having no other issues with my regular apps.

EDIT: I have no issue with the same apps on Windows 10 on another machine, my laptop. Although it takes a few seconds for the browser control to appear, it looks like this.
[image: Browser control in a JRE-Dependent app]

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006c586adf, pid=13788, tid=0x0000000000000ae0
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000002032b800):  JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2784, stack(0x0000000029b00000,0x0000000029c00000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000029bff160, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000022d41310
RSP=0x0000000029bff108, RBP=0x0000000029bff2f0, RSI=0x0000000022e3be38, RDI=0x000000002032b9f8
R8 =0x0000000022d41310, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000029bfc7c0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000029bff310, R14=0x0000000029bff2d8, R15=0x000000002032b800
RIP=0x000000006c586adf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000029bff108)
0x0000000029bff108:   000000006b1b9e16 0000000000000000
0x0000000029bff118:   000000002032b9f8 0000000022e3be38
0x0000000029bff128:   0000000022d41310 000000002032b9f8
0x0000000029bff138:   000000006b1ba7d9 0000000022d41310
0x0000000029bff148:   000000076bb3e910 0000000600000005
0x0000000029bff158:   000000002032b800 0000000000000000
0x0000000029bff168:   0000000000000000 00000000209eb200
0x0000000029bff178:   0000000029bff100 0000000000000000
0x0000000029bff188:   0000000000000000 0000000029bff208
0x0000000029bff198:   000000000345835d 000000002032b800
0x0000000029bff1a8:   000000006b4725f2 0000000000000000
0x0000000029bff1b8:   0000000000000000 000000076b9a0cd8
0x0000000029bff1c8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000029bff1d8:   00000000038463b5 0000000000000058
0x0000000029bff1e8:   0000000029bff240 000000076bb3ef80
0x0000000029bff1f8:   000000076bb3efe8 0000000100000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006c586adf)
0x000000006c586abf:   99 03 00 cc 33 c0 48 8b 5c 24 40 48 8b 74 24 48
0x000000006c586acf:   48 83 c4 30 5f c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 8b c1
0x000000006c586adf:   0f b7 10 48 83 c0 02 66 85 d2 75 f4 48 2b c1 48
0x000000006c586aef:   d1 f8 48 ff c8 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 45 33 c0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000029bff160 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002032b800
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000022d41310 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000029bff108 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002032b800
RBP=0x0000000029bff2f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002032b800
RSI=0x0000000022e3be38 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000002032b9f8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000022d41310 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000029bfc7c0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002032b800
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000029bff310 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002032b800
R14=0x0000000029bff2d8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002032b800
R15=0x000000002032b800 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000029b00000,0x0000000029c00000],  sp=0x0000000029bff108,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2513  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getDisplayNameOf(JJI)Ljava/lang/String; (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000003c0d809 [0x0000000003c0d7c0+0x49]
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$1600(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;+4
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/String;+15
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
J 2524 C1 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V (126 bytes) @ 0x0000000003c12814 [0x0000000003c125c0+0x254]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run()V+7
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

GC Heap History (6 events):
Event: 1.077 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 65536K [0x000000076af00000, 0x0000000770400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 100% used [0x000000076af00000,0x000000076ef00000,0x000000076ef00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f980000,0x000000076f980000,0x0000000770400000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076ef00000,0x000000076ef00000,0x000000076f980000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c0c00000, 0x00000006cb700000, 0x000000076af00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0c00000,0x00000006c0c00000,0x00000006cb700000)
 Metaspace       used 20339K, capacity 20636K, committed 20736K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2698K, capacity 2803K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1.089 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 7313K [0x000000076af00000, 0x0000000774400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 0% used [0x000000076af00000,0x000000076af00000,0x000000076ef00000)
  from space 10752K, 68% used [0x000000076ef00000,0x000000076f624688,0x000000076f980000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000773980000,0x0000000773980000,0x0000000774400000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 96K [0x00000006c0c00000, 0x00000006cb700000, 0x000000076af00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0c00000,0x00000006c0c18010,0x00000006cb700000)
 Metaspace       used 20339K, capacity 20636K, committed 20736K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2698K, capacity 2803K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1.226 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 12098K [0x000000076af00000, 0x0000000774400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 7% used [0x000000076af00000,0x000000076b3ac1c8,0x000000076ef00000)
  from space 10752K, 68% used [0x000000076ef00000,0x000000076f624688,0x000000076f980000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000773980000,0x0000000773980000,0x0000000774400000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 96K [0x00000006c0c00000, 0x00000006cb700000, 0x000000076af00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0c00000,0x00000006c0c18010,0x00000006cb700000)
 Metaspace       used 20977K, capacity 21186K, committed 21296K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2802K, capacity 2900K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1.235 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 141824K, used 5417K [0x000000076af00000, 0x0000000774400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131072K, 0% used [0x000000076af00000,0x000000076af00000,0x0000000772f00000)
  from space 10752K, 50% used [0x0000000773980000,0x0000000773eca4e8,0x0000000774400000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000772f00000,0x0000000772f00000,0x0000000773980000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 104K [0x00000006c0c00000, 0x00000006cb700000, 0x000000076af00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0c00000,0x00000006c0c1a010,0x00000006cb700000)
 Metaspace       used 20977K, capacity 21186K, committed 21296K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2802K, capacity 2900K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1.235 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 141824K, used 5417K [0x000000076af00000, 0x0000000774400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131072K, 0% used [0x000000076af00000,0x000000076af00000,0x0000000772f00000)
  from space 10752K, 50% used [0x0000000773980000,0x0000000773eca4e8,0x0000000774400000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000772f00000,0x0000000772f00000,0x0000000773980000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 104K [0x00000006c0c00000, 0x00000006cb700000, 0x000000076af00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0c00000,0x00000006c0c1a010,0x00000006cb700000)
 Metaspace       used 20977K, capacity 21186K, committed 21296K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2802K, capacity 2900K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1.264 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 141824K, used 0K [0x000000076af00000, 0x0000000774400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131072K, 0% used [0x000000076af00000,0x000000076af00000,0x0000000772f00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000773980000,0x0000000773980000,0x0000000774400000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000772f00000,0x0000000772f00000,0x0000000773980000)
 ParOldGen       total 97280K, used 5001K [0x00000006c0c00000, 0x00000006c6b00000, 0x000000076af00000)
  object space 97280K, 5% used [0x00000006c0c00000,0x00000006c10e2768,0x00000006c6b00000)
 Metaspace       used 20937K, capacity 21126K, committed 21296K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2797K, capacity 2888K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 1.040 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000038065a0 method=java.util.HashSet.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 1.040 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000038065a0 method=java.util.HashSet.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 1.040 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000384b5a0 method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 253
Event: 1.040 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000384b5a0 method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 253
Event: 1.183 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000393ef38 method=javax.swing.text.Segment.next()C @ 25
Event: 5.134 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000036e530c method=java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(I)V @ 5
Event: 5.134 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003947fd8 method=java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(I)V @ 5
Event: 6.385 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003badc9c method=java.security.AccessControlContext.optimize()Ljava/security/AccessControlContext; @ 220
Event: 6.529 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000386dd2c method=java.util.Hashtable.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 48
Event: 6.532 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000039341f0 method=java.util.Hashtable.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 63

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.168 Thread 0x000000000193e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x000000076b2779e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.431 Thread 0x000000000193e000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000003669497 to 0x0000000003669879
Event: 0.431 Thread 0x000000000193e000 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x000000076d9181d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 0.431 Thread 0x000000000193e000 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x000000076d918800) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 0.435 Thread 0x000000000193e000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000076d91c400) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 0.554 Thread 0x000000000193e000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000076dd37a20) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 0.576 Thread 0x000000000193e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': <clinit>> (0x000000076df424b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 1613]
Event: 0.751 Thread 0x000000000193e000 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000036fc014 to 0x00000000036fc3dd
Event: 1.092 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError'> (0x000000076af0b710) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 3978]
Event: 1.092 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Exception <a 'java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError'> (0x000000076af0b710) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 6.496 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$11
Event: 6.496 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$11 done
Event: 6.529 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x000000000386dd2c
Event: 6.529 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 6.529 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 6.529 Thread 0x000000002075e000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x000000000386dd2c sp=0x0000000026f4bae0
Event: 6.529 Thread 0x000000002075e000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000349582a sp=0x0000000026f4ba88 mode 2
Event: 6.532 Thread 0x000000002075e000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x00000000039341f0
Event: 6.532 Thread 0x000000002075e000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000039341f0 sp=0x0000000026f4baa0
Event: 6.532 Thread 0x000000002075e000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000349582a sp=0x0000000026f4ba70 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6e64d0000 - 0x00007ff6e6507000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007ffd11420000 - 0x00007ffd115fb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffd0ea60000 - 0x00007ffd0eb0e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffd0da40000 - 0x00007ffd0dc89000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffd0be60000 - 0x00007ffd0bede000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffd0f1d0000 - 0x00007ffd0f271000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffd0f130000 - 0x00007ffd0f1cd000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffd10b40000 - 0x00007ffd10b99000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffd112f0000 - 0x00007ffd11415000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffd109f0000 - 0x00007ffd10b3a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffd0ddf0000 - 0x00007ffd0de0e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffd0eb10000 - 0x00007ffd0eb37000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffd0e7f0000 - 0x00007ffd0e979000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffd0de10000 - 0x00007ffd0deaa000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffd0d940000 - 0x00007ffd0da36000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffd06020000 - 0x00007ffd06287000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.0_none_108e4f62dfe5d999\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffd10ed0000 - 0x00007ffd111c9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffd0e780000 - 0x00007ffd0e7ea000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffd10cf0000 - 0x00007ffd10d1d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x000000006c550000 - 0x000000006c622000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006b2f0000 - 0x000000006bb8a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffd0f120000 - 0x00007ffd0f128000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffd095d0000 - 0x00007ffd095da000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffcf8360000 - 0x00007ffcf8369000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffd0bd50000 - 0x00007ffd0bd73000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffd108a0000 - 0x00007ffd1090c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffd0bd20000 - 0x00007ffd0bd4b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffd0dda0000 - 0x00007ffd0dde9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x000000006c540000 - 0x000000006c54f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006c510000 - 0x000000006c539000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.dll
0x000000006c4f0000 - 0x000000006c506000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffd0f460000 - 0x00007ffd10897000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffd111e0000 - 0x00007ffd1128a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffd0deb0000 - 0x00007ffd0e5a2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffd0f280000 - 0x00007ffd0f2d1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffd0d920000 - 0x00007ffd0d931000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffd0d8d0000 - 0x00007ffd0d91c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffd0d8b0000 - 0x00007ffd0d8c5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x000000006b150000 - 0x000000006b2e8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\awt.dll
0x00007ffd0e9a0000 - 0x00007ffd0ea5f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000000006c180000 - 0x000000006c19a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffd0d1a0000 - 0x00007ffd0d1fc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffcf8340000 - 0x00007ffcf8356000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\napinsp.dll
0x00007ffcf82d0000 - 0x00007ffcf82ea000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x00007ffd0add0000 - 0x00007ffd0ade8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x00007ffd0cf90000 - 0x00007ffd0d034000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00007ffd111d0000 - 0x00007ffd111d8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffd0cf40000 - 0x00007ffd0cf77000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ffcf82c0000 - 0x00007ffcf82ce000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x00007ffd00490000 - 0x00007ffd0049a000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x00007ffd01f50000 - 0x00007ffd01fbb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x00007ffd0d450000 - 0x00007ffd0d475000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ffd0c030000 - 0x00007ffd0c0c5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ffd0f2f0000 - 0x00007ffd0f456000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffd0b9e0000 - 0x00007ffd0ba0a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ffd10ba0000 - 0x00007ffd10ce4000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffcda300000 - 0x00007ffcda489000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
0x00007ffd07970000 - 0x00007ffd07a4f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_274d0ab8ee30c459\nvldumdx.dll
0x00007ffd0e5b0000 - 0x00007ffd0e779000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\crypt32.dll
0x00007ffd0d890000 - 0x00007ffd0d8a1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007ffd0dd40000 - 0x00007ffd0dd96000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.DLL
0x00007ffd0e980000 - 0x00007ffd0e99d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll
0x00007ffd0d340000 - 0x00007ffd0d357000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00007ffd0cdc0000 - 0x00007ffd0cdf4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ffd0d360000 - 0x00007ffd0d36b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x00007ffcd91d0000 - 0x00007ffcda1e4000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_274d0ab8ee30c459\nvd3dumx.dll
0x00007ffd05d50000 - 0x00007ffd05f21000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvspcap64.dll
0x00007ffd0eb40000 - 0x00007ffd0ef7b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x00007ffd05c70000 - 0x00007ffd05d47000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
0x00007ffd0b5d0000 - 0x00007ffd0b5e3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ffd04670000 - 0x00007ffd04a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvapi64.dll
0x00007ffd0c700000 - 0x00007ffd0c7a4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
0x00007ffd05f30000 - 0x00007ffd06017000     C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\3D Vision\nvSCPAPI64.dll
0x000000006c130000 - 0x000000006c177000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x000000006c110000 - 0x000000006c121000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\nio.dll
0x000000006c0c0000 - 0x000000006c102000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\t2k.dll
0x00007ffd0d7c0000 - 0x00007ffd0d7e9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffd01d80000 - 0x00007ffd01d96000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ffd01d20000 - 0x00007ffd01d3a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x00007ffcf3750000 - 0x00007ffcf3761000     C:\Users\Hop\AppData\Local\Temp\ShellLink_x644521000185514866325.dll
0x00007ffd10e30000 - 0x00007ffd10ece000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ffd0bb20000 - 0x00007ffd0bcb6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
0x00007ffd08990000 - 0x00007ffd08a12000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\TextInputFramework.dll
0x00007ffd08fe0000 - 0x00007ffd092b2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
0x00007ffd0adf0000 - 0x00007ffd0aed3000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
0x00007ffd0cbf0000 - 0x00007ffd0cc21000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
0x00007ffd09830000 - 0x00007ffd09969000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
0x00007ffd0a600000 - 0x00007ffd0a615000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\usermgrcli.dll
0x00007ffd09420000 - 0x00007ffd095cc000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x00007ffcefa00000 - 0x00007ffcefa47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dataexchange.dll
0x00007ffd0b5f0000 - 0x00007ffd0b712000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dcomp.dll
0x00007ffd0aaf0000 - 0x00007ffd0adcf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d11.dll
0x00007ffd0c2d0000 - 0x00007ffd0c440000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
0x00007ffd08400000 - 0x00007ffd084a6000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.15063.0_none_43a14f3b47f396e6\comctl32.dll
0x00007ffce71f0000 - 0x00007ffce7317000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
0x00007ffd07ec0000 - 0x00007ffd083f1000     C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll
0x00007ffcef510000 - 0x00007ffcef567000     C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll
0x00007ffd07ab0000 - 0x00007ffd07b26000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
0x00007ffd04350000 - 0x00007ffd043df000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcp110_win.dll
0x00007ffcf3970000 - 0x00007ffcf398b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffcf20c0000 - 0x00007ffcf20cb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\drprov.dll
0x00007ffd0c9f0000 - 0x00007ffd0ca45000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINSTA.dll
0x00007ffd08bb0000 - 0x00007ffd08bc6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntlanman.dll
0x00007ffd08b90000 - 0x00007ffd08bb0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\davclnt.dll
0x00007ffd08b80000 - 0x00007ffd08b8c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
0x00007ffd08860000 - 0x00007ffd08876000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wkscli.dll
0x00007ffd007a0000 - 0x00007ffd007b2000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
0x00007ffd0cf80000 - 0x00007ffd0cf8d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\netutils.dll
0x00007ffce10d0000 - 0x00007ffce111a000     C:\Windows\System32\dlnashext.dll
0x00007ffce3b90000 - 0x00007ffce3bfd000     C:\Windows\System32\PlayToDevice.dll
0x00007ffce3b50000 - 0x00007ffce3b6e000     C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll
0x00007ffd08880000 - 0x00007ffd088e7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x00007ffd0c2a0000 - 0x00007ffd0c2c8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007ffcd83f0000 - 0x00007ffcd85cf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wpdshext.dll
0x00007ffd084b0000 - 0x00007ffd08645000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.15063.0_none_9055be80f37df5c1\gdiplus.dll
0x00007ffd0a1e0000 - 0x00007ffd0a27c000     C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceApi.dll
0x00007ffcf4590000 - 0x00007ffcf45c1000     C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceTypes.dll
0x00007ffce96b0000 - 0x00007ffce96e6000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorShell.dll
0x00007ffd02200000 - 0x00007ffd02225000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorAPI.dll
0x00007ffcee580000 - 0x00007ffcee590000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll
0x00007ffcff550000 - 0x00007ffcff55c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
0x00007ffd0d790000 - 0x00007ffd0d7c0000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
0x00007ffd05460000 - 0x00007ffd05478000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\samcli.dll
0x00007ffd0b720000 - 0x00007ffd0b743000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SAMLIB.dll
0x00007ffcf97d0000 - 0x00007ffcf9979000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
java_command: O:\embedded_dev\downloads\STLINK and OPENOCD\STM32CubeL1\stm32cubemx\SetupSTM32CubeMX-4.20.1.exe
java_class_path (initial): O:\embedded_dev\downloads\STLINK and OPENOCD\STM32CubeL1\stm32cubemx\SetupSTM32CubeMX-4.20.1.exe
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
```

Comment: Check your Windows 10 security settings. Also, Make sure Java is indeed enabled. In the Start menu locate **Java** ---> **Configure Java**. Within the displayed **Java Control Panel** dialog select the **Security** tab. You might also see if your anti-virus software is preventing your application from running, try disabling it for a moment.

Comment: Disabled A/V, checked the Java control panel but all I saw to enable was Java in a browser and security tab... settings are at the lowest. There use to be three settings but now there are two... High and Very High. The STM32CUBE installer did write an error log file though and this is the first time I have seen this. It is rather large, but I updated the OP to show it.

Comment: Tracked msvcr100.dll+0x36adf error which led me to another unanswered post here and a link. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178846?jql=text%20~%20%22msvcr100.dll%2B0x36adf%22 and it is more common than I thought. My flavor of the issue appears to be JDK-8179014 - JFileChooser with Windows look and feel crashes on win 10. No fix yet but at least I have a research path to follow now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one really threw me! This will occur if you have a windows 10 God Mode shortcut on your desktop. Once I removed it, the problem vanished. Apparently, the JFileChooser or msvcr100.dll has an issue with the shortcut and throws an error. Removing the GodMode shortcut solved the problem. The GodMode shortcut is a technet trick to show a folder like listing of all the Windows settings. I have been using it since Windows 7. At least until now I guess. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2010/01/08/windows-7-godmode-and-other-folder-shortcuts/

Comment: WOW, this worked for me.  "thank you" does not begin to express it. (plus the +1)